# Chromatic Number of Graph G = (V,E) <= 1 + max{deg(v)|v is a member of V}

Tags: discrete-mathematics

[My Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9wxS.png)

I have understand the problem however am having a hard time proving it. I thought I could maybe go with the most extreme example where the graph is a complete graph and in that case the chromatic number is literally the max(deg(v)) + 1. Is that enough? Sorry did not explain very well but any help would be appreciated. P.S. This is not a homework problem but a question on a final review sheet so it is not worth any points... unless it shows up on the exam tomorrow.

Comment: To be a bit more rigorous, you could show that the chromatic number of a graph is at least the chromatic number of any of its subgraphs.

Answer (score 0):

No, that is not enough, because you could imagine a graph with a lower maximum degree $d$ than the number of vertices, and then you must non-trivially show that you can color that graph with $d+1$ colors.

My approach would be to start by saying that if there is a graph with no vertex of degree at greater than  $d$ that cannot be $d+1$-colored, then there is a minimal graph of that nature, and proceed to show that there exists a vertex that can be removed without relaxing the need for more than $d+1$ colors.  This proof will be much easier than the 4-color proof, because planarity is not a consideration here.

Comment: How would I prove that there exists a vertex that can be removed w/o relaxing the need for more than d + 1 colors? Like how would I formally prove that??